# Model record/instance specific view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have 8 plans for the user to choose from. These plans all represents forms which would results in products added into the cart.

A few plans will ask different questions. For example plan A,B,C would ask the user if he/she want to purchase additional addon. Plan D,E would ask the user the total credit  to store in their account.

This seems to suggest that we have separate views for each of the plan. But this means we then need to add show and edit actions for each of the plan. A bit tedious. So I want to ask if there is a pattern for having record specific view in Rails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure if this can be answered in any specific conclusive way, but I would use partials in such a case.

let's assume your plan has a `type` field somewhere you could do the following

```
<%= render partial: "plan_#{@plan.type}" %>
```

Whereas each of these `_plan_X.html.erb` partials contains the plan specific information you want to display.
This pattern can be adopted for all of your views (maybe your edit action has different data depending on your plan type etc.